# Can I mirror request data with Charles Proxy?

Tags: charles-proxy

The mirror feature in Charles Proxy saves the responses -- I want to see the requests that are made for the corresponding saved response outside of the Charles UI so that I can programmatically match some of the data in the request to the response.

For instance, I might have a request to `mysite.com/data?param=123` that results in the file `data` with the response value `{"param": 123}`. Then I might have another request `mysite.com/data?param=456` and the same file `data` with a different response value.

I want to match the original request to the saved response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Auto Save](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/auto-save/) feature of Charles.

In "Charles - Tools - Auto Save", enable this feature and take "Save type" as "JSON Session File":

[image]

Then, all requests and corresponding responses will be saved as JSON data, which is pretty good for programming.